# Getting errors with os.listdir within flask and heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku, listdir

I have an application that, takes the url and returns a files corresponding to it. I wanted to push it on heroku but i get this error : 
 **File "/app/server.py", line 1525, in upload1

```
music = os.listdir(foldername)
```

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'favicon.ico'**

Then i tried to add favicon.ico in all of the folders and i am getting

**File "/app/server.py", line 1525, in upload1

```
music = os.listdir(foldername)
```

NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: 'favicon.ico'**

The part where it looks to struggle is

```py
    @app.route('/<path:foldername>')
    def upload1(foldername):
        music = os.listdir(foldername)
        print(music)
        path_to_file = music[0]

        return send_file(
        foldername+"/"+path_to_file,
        mimetype="audio/mp3", 
        as_attachment=True, 
        attachment_filename=path_to_file )
```

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is, you have to set `UPLOAD_FOLDER` path in config like.

`UPLOAD_FOLDER = "your folder name"`
then you can get the file path like.

`file_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"], filename))`

you can get more information from [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/)

Comment: I see, but how could i upload the file in the folder without knowing its name? The problem is that i cannot use os.listdir. Your solution looks to have to know the name of the file we want to upload

Comment: Have you checked the link that I shared

Comment: And do you know the folder name ? Or you are searching it in every folder?

Comment: Yes i know the folder name but not the filename inside of it. ( there is only one file into the folder) and yes i checked the link and it looks like it needs both filename and foldername.

Comment: ok, and you are picking filename from a route, right?
your route may have filename as you mentioned ` @app.route('/<path:filename>')`.

so now you know the foldername and filename with you, so whats the problem

Comment: oh i written filename but it is the foldername, my bad

Comment: yeah, I have added another answer for you, don't forget to accept the answer if it helps :D

Comment: no i didnt meant it in this way sorry, i meant that i wrote filename in my code but it actually gets foldername, and i dont get filename . Sorry. I edited my original question

Comment: try if this works
folder_path = os.path.abspath(foldername)
music = os.listdir(folder_path)

Answer (score 0):

```
@app.route('/<path:foldername>')
    def upload1(foldername):
        abs_path = os.path.abspath(foldername)
        music = os.listdir(abs_path)
        path_to_file = os.path.join(abs_path, music[0])

        return send_file(
        foldername+"/"+path_to_file,
        mimetype="audio/mp3", 
        as_attachment=True, 
        attachment_filename=path_to_file )
```

it will first take the foldername from param and then convert into abspath.
then listdir would list all the files, then it will take first file from list and join path.

Comment: @Falseee I updated the answer, it would work! :).
the only thing is your folder should be in root directory.

Comment: Yes it does :) mine does also, i just forgot to add the /(myfilename) after the url ... I'm so dumb. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I feel dumb right now. the issue is that when i did heroku open i got the error instantly. But i got it because i didnt add anything after the url ( so the code would obviously not work )